# Filtering terms in list view (Drupal)

Tags: php, drupal

I have a website which I have taken over and I am new to drupal & PHP.

Basically there is a content filter on one of the pages --- When you select a term from the drop down list, it filters all the content which that term is grouped in.

I am trying to figure out how to add all my Parent terms into the drop down list, so that when a user select a term, it filters all the content within that term.

Currently there are only 4 in the menu, and I have a total of 13 in my Taxonomy.

you can see it live in action here http://www.buymondo.co.za/devices/phones

the list drop-down is on the right-hand side with a heading of MANUFACTURER

any help would be appreciated 
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a View named "Devices" in your Views UI. You can see it in your Admin Dashboard.

You have to edit this view and click in the filter section. 
I dont know whats the name of your vocabulary, but I sure you can change the depth of the terms to show. I think that you are displaying only the last depth.

I also dont know whats the structure of your vocabulary, but normally you have more than 1 level.

I hope this information has useful.

Regards.